# Dar vuelta una frase de un string con un for, por qué tira error?

Tags: javascript, string, bucle-for

```
function asAmirror(str) {
  //La función recibe una frase. 
  //Escribe una función que tome la frase recibida y la devuelva de modo tal que se pueda leer de izquierda a derecha 
  //pero con cada una de sus palabras invertidas, como si fuera un espejo.
  
  //Escribe tu código aquí

  let reverse = "";

  for(let i = str.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
    reverse += str[i];
  }
  return reverse;
}
```

No sé donde está el error, ya que al dar vuelta la frase no lo hace por letra si no por palabras, estoy tratando de evitar de solucionarlo con split('').reverse().join('');

El error que me tira es:
● asAmirror(str) › should return the string recieved with all the words reversed as a
mirror

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "I evol uoy os !hcum"
Received: "!hcum os uoy evol "

  35 | describe('asAmirror(str)', function() {
  36 |   it('should return the string recieved with all the words reversed as a mirror', function() {
> 37 |     expect(asAmirror("I love you so much!")).toBe("I evol uoy os !hcum");    
     |                                              ^
  38 |     expect(asAmirror("The Henry Challenge is close!")).toBe("ehT yrneH egnellahC si !esolc");
  39 |   });
  40 | });
```

Comment: Si sabes que ```.toBe()``` se usa para comparar?

Answer (score 4):

El error lo tienes en que es `i>=0` no `i>0` quedaría así `for(let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`.

Lo puedes hacer de otras formas también formas

```
function asAmirror(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Recursivo

```
function asAmirror(str) {
  if (str === "") //Este seria el caso termila
    return "";
  else
    return reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, cuidado con tu condición, el control debe ser `i >= 0` para que se comporte como esperas.

```javascript
// i >= 0 en lugar de i > 0
for(let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  ...
}
```

Por otra parte, te aconsejo hacerlo así:

```javascript
function reverseString (str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function asAmirror(str) {
 var espejo = '';
   for(let i = str.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
     espejo += str[i];
   };
  return espejo.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
}
```

> asAmirror("I love you so much!")//.toBe("I evol uoy os !hcum");
>
> asAmirror("The Henry Challenge is close!")//.toBe("ehT yrneH egnellahC
> si !esolc");

Comment: Es recomendable que agregues una explicación de tu solución, no solo para el que hace la pregunta sino también para otros que puedan verla.

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución fue esta:

```js
function asAmirror(str) {
  let strProv = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  return strProv.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
} 

console.log(asAmirror("The Henry Challenge is close!"));
```

Porque la que proponen otros usuarios cambia de orden las palabras, y lo que se debe cambiar es el orden de las letras de cada palabra, y no el orden de las palabras.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function asAmirror(str) {
    //La función recibe una frase. 
    //Escribe una función que tome la frase recibida y la devuelva de modo tal que se pueda leer de izquierda a derecha 
    //pero con cada una de sus palabras invertidas, como si fuera un espejo.
    //Ej: Recibe ---> "The Henry Challenge is close!" || Devuelve ---> "ehT yrneH egnellahC si !esolc"
    //Escribe tu código aquí
    let mirror = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {// recorremos el string
        if (str[i] === " ") {// si en el indice hay un espacio
            mirror = "-" + mirror;// concatena un guion- para ver el espaciado
        }else{// de lo contrario concatena lo que hay en el indice con el mirror
           mirror = str[i] + mirror; // hola => h + '', o + h, l + oh, a + loh = aloh
        }
    }
    return mirror.split("-").reverse().join(" ");//.split() separa por valores guion- en palabras, .rever() invierte en orden de las palabras y .join() junta todo con "espacio" entre cada palabra 
    }
const str = "The Henry Challenge is close!";
console.log(asAmirror(str));
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta _por qué tira error  asAmirror(str) › should return the string recieved with all the words reversed as a mirror_ ?